# Unable to configure yum ftp repository

Tags: linux, fedora, repository, ftp, dnf

I managed to configure successfully an ftp repository access using the default directory /var/ftp/pub using the anonymous user
I could install and download packages from node.

Now i am trying to change the default directory, i added anon_root=/srv/pub to /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf and i configured selinux and give all rights to the dir.
I am able to connect manually using ftp with anonymous user to the remote directory and i can see all the packages.

But when using dnf, i m getting those errors :

```
errors during downloading metadata for repository 'ftp_remote':
  - Curl error (9): Access denied to remote resource for ftp://192.168.1.67/pub/repodata/repomd.xml [Server denied you to change to the given directory]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'ftp_remote': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

My repo configuration file on the node client is :

```
[ftp_remote]
name=ftp
baseurl=ftp://192.168.1.67/pub
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error,
Apparently the repository can't be configured the same as anon_root
The repo should be at least a subdirectory under anon_root.

So in vsftpd.conf on server :
anon_root=/srv/pub

I configured the repo to be :
/srv/pub/packages

Configuration file on node client :

```
[ftp_remote]
name=ftp
baseurl=ftp://192.168.1.67/packages
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```